# Python list of lists of tuples transformation

Tags: python, string, list, input, tuples

My **single input**, given as **string** is a list of lists of tuples, for example:

> [[('STRING1', 2), ('STRING2', 7), ('STRING3', 12), ('STRING4', 17),
>   ('STRING5', 21)], [('STRING1', 10), ('STRING2', 15), ('STRING3', 21),
>   ('STRING4', 24), ('STRING5', 28)], [('STRING1', 17), ('STRING2', 22),
>   ('STRING3', 29), ('STRING4', 32), ('STRING5', 36)], [('STRING1', 22),
>   ('STRING2', 30), ('STRING3', 37), ('STRING4', 40), ('STRING5', 45)]]

What I want in result is to get lists of all values next to specific strings, for example:

```
STRING1 = [2, 10, 17, 22]
STRING2 = [7, 15, 22, 30]
STRING3 = [12, 21, 29, 37]
STRING4 = [17, 24, 32, 40]
STRING5 = [21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Or to any other format that will let me operate on that input easily.

Comment: You can use a dictionary for accumulation.

Comment: I tried to separate the whole input by looking for ")]", and creating sub-lists. In the end I had list of 5 lists, each in format "[('STRING1', int), ('STRING2', int), ('STRING3', int), ('STRING4', int), ('STRING5', int)]"
But no idea what my next step should be

Comment: Is your question how to parse your data from a string? If it's valid Python syntax, you can call `ast.literal_eval` on it to turn it into the corresponding Python data structure. You could also use the builtin `eval`, but `ast.literal_eval` is safer (since it doesn't allow arbitrary expressions, like function calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is in the form of a string, it'll need to be parsed first. This can be done with `ast.literal_eval.`

```
import ast
from collections import defaultdict

input_str = """[[('STRING1', 2), ('STRING2', 7), ('STRING3', 12), ('STRING4', 17), ('STRING5', 21)], [('STRING1', 10), ('STRING2', 15), ('STRING3', 21), ('STRING4', 24), ('STRING5', 28)], [('STRING1', 17), ('STRING2', 22), ('STRING3', 29), ('STRING4', 32), ('STRING5', 36)], [('STRING1', 22), ('STRING2', 30), ('STRING3', 37), ('STRING4', 40), ('STRING5', 45)]]"""

data = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
    for x, y in d:
        data_dict[x].append(y)


for k in data_dict:
    print(k, '=', data_dict[k])
```

Output:

```
STRING2 = [7, 15, 22, 30]
STRING4 = [17, 24, 32, 40]
STRING5 = [21, 28, 36, 45]
STRING3 = [12, 21, 29, 37]
STRING1 = [2, 10, 17, 22]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the list literal into a list object. Then you could use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to accumulate the values from the tuples:

```
>>> L = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for lst in L:
...     for t in lst:
...         d[t[0]].append(t[1])
... 
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     print(k, v)
... 
STRING1 [2, 10, 17, 22]
STRING2 [7, 15, 22, 30]
STRING3 [12, 21, 29, 37]
STRING4 [17, 24, 32, 40]
STRING5 [21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `STRING1`, `STRING2` are in the same indices in each list you can try using `zip`.

```
x = ([('STRING1', 2), ('STRING2', 7), ('STRING3', 12), ('STRING4', 17), ('STRING5', 21)], 
     [('STRING1', 10), ('STRING2', 15), ('STRING3', 21), ('STRING4', 24), ('STRING5', 28)], 
     [('STRING1', 17), ('STRING2', 22), ('STRING3', 29), ('STRING4', 32), ('STRING5', 36)], 
     [('STRING1', 22), ('STRING2', 30), ('STRING3', 37), ('STRING4', 40), ('STRING5', 45)])

for items in zip(*x):
    values = [item[1] for item in items]
    print values

# [2, 10, 17, 22]
# [7, 15, 22, 30]
# [12, 21, 29, 37]
# [17, 24, 32, 40]
# [21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Answer (score -1):

Will this help?

```
data = [[('STRING1', 2), ('STRING2', 7), ('STRING3', 12), ('STRING4', 17), ('STRING5', 21)], [('STRING1', 10), ('STRING2', 15), ('STRING3', 21), ('STRING4', 24), ('STRING5', 28)], [('STRING1', 17), ('STRING2', 22), ('STRING3', 29), ('STRING4', 32), ('STRING5', 36)], [('STRING1', 22), ('STRING2', 30), ('STRING3', 37), ('STRING4', 40), ('STRING5', 45)]]
data_dict = {}
for row in data:
  for key, value in row:
    data_dict[key] = data_dict.get(key, []) + [value]
```

if you want to set variables using the strings as names, you can try

```
for key, value in data_dict.items():
  vars()[key] = value
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can't define variable names in execution time, so dictionary in this cases is the best solution. I used regex to identify words on the string and then insert it on the dict of lists structure. The solution is as follows:

```
import re


s = """"[[('STRING1', 2), ('STRING2', 7), ('STRING3', 12), ('STRING4', 17), ('STRING5', 21)], 
        [('STRING1', 10), ('STRING2', 15), ('STRING3', 21), ('STRING4', 24), ('STRING5', 28)], 
        [('STRING1', 17), ('STRING2', 22), ('STRING3', 29), ('STRING4', 32), ('STRING5', 36)], 
        [('STRING1', 22), ('STRING2', 30), ('STRING3', 37), ('STRING4', 40), ('STRING5', 45)]]"""


data = dict()

pattern = re.compile("\('([^,']+)',[ ]*([0-9]+)\)")

regex = re.findall(pattern, s, flags=0)

if regex:
    for (k, v) in regex:
        if k not in data:
            data[k] = []
        data[k] += [int(v)]

print(data)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict  
d = defaultdict(list)

list(map(lambda x: d[x[0]].append(x[1]), chain(*list_of_lists)))
```

Comment: It's good to include an explanation of your code in the answer.